# Is there a predefined library supporting all use cases for AWS SWF deciders

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-batch, aws-sdk, amazon-swf

In Amazon SWF the decider has to be implemented by the developer and has to write the code to support all use cases. I need to implement a workflow architecture which can support execution of tasks in sequential, branching, parallel. Is there a predefined library which can take the definition of the workflow and execute the tasks.
I am looking at a library similar to Spring Batch in which if I give the workflow definition in xml format it will execute all the tasks without any custom decider code.

Comment: Having that any nontrivial workflow requires code execution to evaluate conditions and to pass data, defining it in pure XML is not really feasible. At the same time it is really simple to create simple domain specific language on top of SWF. See deployment sample from AWS Java SDK.